# Play Framework JSON Parsing Error

Tags: json, playframework

I have the following data type:

```
case class DataPoints(fromSource: String, dataPoints: Seq[DataPoint])
object DataPoints {

  implicit val tsFormat = Json.format[DataPoint]

  implicit val tsDataPointsFormat: Format[DataPoints] =
    ((__ \ "fromSource").format[String] ~
      (__ \ "dataPoints").format[Seq[DataPoint]]
      )(DataPoints.apply, unlift(DataPoints.unapply))
}
```

In the place where I use this Json conversion:

```
  private def toDataPointSeq(consumerRecords: Seq[ConsumerRecord[String, String]]) = {
    import com.model.DataPoints._
    consumerRecords.map {
      case record =>
        logger.info(s"value obtained is ${record.value()}")
        val jsonIs = Json.toJson(record.value()).validate[DataPoints].asOpt
        logger.info(s"json obtained is $jsonIs") // prints None
        jsonIs
    }.collect {
      case someDataPts if someDataPts.isDefined => someDataPts.get.dataPoints
    }
  }
```

The json that I get is returned as None even though the line record.value() prints the folowing:

```
{  
   "fromSource":"kafkaProducer",
   "dataPoints":[  
      {  
         "metric":"dataPoint.Active",
         "timestamp":1453830484838,
         "value":0.0,
         "tags":{  
            "Id":"100"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Any ideas as to why I see None after validating the Json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why and where the problem is. Actually, I'm getting the values from Kafka as Json, but that Json contains additional escape characters like this:

```
"{\"fromSource\":\"kafkaProducer\",\"dataPoints\":
```

I had to do additional parsing to un-escape the escape characters!